# Expectation value of quantum annihilation operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space

I already know the expectation value of a quantum annihilation operator $\hat{a} $. I want to find the expectation value of quantum creation operator $\hat{a}^\dagger$. Is it equal to following?

$$\langle\hat{a}^\dagger\rangle = \langle\hat{a}\rangle^* $$

$\langle\hat{a}\rangle^*$ is complex conjugate of the expectation value of $\hat{a}$.

Comment: @Qmechanic I mistakenly put it as a Hermitian operator.  But I really wanted to find the expectation value of the Hermitian conjugate operator  $\hat{a}^\dagger $ given the expectation value of $\hat{a} $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is helpful here to remember that the expectation value $\langle \hat{a} \rangle$ is taken with respect to a quantum state $|\psi \rangle$ (or a density operator, but let's keep it simple). In this case,
$$
\langle \hat{a} \rangle = \langle \psi | \hat{a} | \psi \rangle
$$Recall now that $\langle \phi | \hat{O} | \psi\rangle^* = \langle \psi | \hat{O}^\dagger|\phi\rangle$. An intuitive picture for this relation comes from the matrix element interpretation of these objects - ie., a linear operator $\hat{O}$ can be expressed as an $N \times N$ matrix where $N$ is the dimension of the Hilbert space. In this case, the 'dagger' operator is the conjugate transpose, so the '$\psi$ by $\phi$'-th element of $\hat{O}^\dagger$ is the complex conjugate of the '$\phi$ by $\psi$'-th element of $\hat{O}$.

Given this relation,
$$
\langle \hat{a} \rangle^* = \langle \psi|\hat{a}|\psi\rangle ^* = \langle \psi | \hat{a}^\dagger |\psi\rangle = \langle \hat{a}^\dagger \rangle.
$$
So indeed the expectation values of $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{a}^\dagger$ are complex conjugates.